# JQuery Pie Timer behaves oddly when in setInterval

Tags: jquery, timer

I found this [Pie Timer](http://codepen.io/elaelation/pen/CxgmH/) and modified it a little, so it'd fit to my project (changed colors and size). I need it to execute every 12 seconds, so I put it in setInterval function. Here is how it looks now: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ctkp1oet/2/)**
There are two problems though:

1. When executed for first time it waits for 12 seconds to start. How to get rid of this initial delay?
2. Only first cycle goes fully. All the next runs starts from the halfway, not from the beginning.

Whereas I could live with the initial delay, this go-from-the-middle thing is killing me. Is there any way to fix it?

```
function pieTimer(){    
    var totaltime = 120;
    function update(percent){
        var deg;
        if (percent<(totaltime/2)){
            deg = 90 + (360*percent/totaltime);
            $('.pie').css('background-image',
            'linear-gradient('+deg+'deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)'
            );
        } 
        else if (percent>=(totaltime/2)){
            deg = -90 + (360*percent/totaltime);
            $('.pie').css('background-image',
            'linear-gradient('+deg+'deg, transparent 50%, #e31630 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)'
            );
        }   
    }
    var count = parseInt($('#time').text());
    myCounter = setInterval(function () {
        count+=1;
        $('#time').html(count);
        update(count);

        if(count==totaltime)
             clearInterval(myCounter);
    }, 100);
}
setInterval(pieTimer, 12000);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first point just call the function before the end of the body or use jQuery document ready statement.

```
<body>
<div class="pie degree">
        <span class="block"></span>
        <span id="time">0</span>
    </div>
    <script>pieTimer();</script>
</body>
```

for the second point you have to reset count variable when it's equal to totaltime

```
function pieTimer(){    
    var totaltime = 120;
    function update(percent){
        var deg;
        if (percent<(totaltime/2)){
            deg = 90 + (360*percent/totaltime);
            $('.pie').css('background-image',
            'linear-gradient('+deg+'deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)'
            );
        } 
        else if (percent>=(totaltime/2)){
            deg = -90 + (360*percent/totaltime);
            $('.pie').css('background-image',
            'linear-gradient('+deg+'deg, transparent 50%, #e31630 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)'
            );
        }   
    }
    var count = parseInt($('#time').text());
    myCounter = setInterval(function () {
        count+=1;
        $('#time').html(count);
        update(count);

        if(count==totaltime){
            clearInterval(myCounter);
            count = 0;
        }

    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider a more up-to-date approach, heavily based on the code in the question but encapsulated in a constructor function, which allows :

- parameters to be passed in, to control the timer's behaviour.
- .start() and .stop() methods to be called from outside.
- multiple, independent timers on the same page, if desired.

Changes the internal logic allow :

- better timing - based on a timeout, not an (ugly) counter incremented in a setInterval.
- update interval independent of totaltime.

And by returning a Promise from the .start() method, control can be exercised *externally* over :

- what happens when a timer expires.
- what happens if a timer is stopped prematurely.

Here's the constructor ...

```
function PieTimer(containerSelector, interval, totaltime) {
    var $container = $(containerSelector),
        myCounter,
        dfrd;

    // input range checks
    if($container.length === 0) return;
    interval = Math.max(+interval || 0, 50);
    totaltime = Math.max(+totaltime || 0, 1000);

    function update(t0) {
        var p = (Date.now() - t0) / totaltime, // proportion, from 0.0 to 1.0
            deg; 
        if (p < 0.5) {
            deg = 90 + 360 * p;
            $container.css('background-image', 'linear-gradient('+deg+'deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)');
        } else if (p >= 0.5) {
            deg = -90 + 360 * p;
            $container.css('background-image', 'linear-gradient('+deg+'deg, transparent 50%, #e31630 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)');
        }
    }
    //Public start method
    this.start = function() {
        this.stop("timer was restarted before expiry"); // in case .start() is called while timer is still running.
        myCounter = setInterval(update.bind(null, new Date()), interval); //animate the timer
        dfrd = $.Deferred(function(dfrd) { // create a Deferred object
            setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, totaltime); // resolve the Deferred after the totaltime period
        });
        return dfrd.then(this.stop); // stop the timer when the Deferred resolves, and return a promise based on the Deferred. Note, `dfrd.reject()` will have no effect as `dfrd.resolve()` has already been called.
    };
    //Public stop method
    this.stop = function(msg) {
        msg = msg || 'timer was stopped before expiry';
        clearInterval(myCounter); // stop the animation
        if(dfrd) {
            dfrd.reject(new Error(msg)); // provide a reason why the timer was stopped, and allow some external action to be taken.
        }
    };
}
```

And here's how to use it ...

```
var pieTimer = new PieTimer(".pie", 100, 12000);
(function runTimer() {
    pieTimer.start().then(runTimer);
})();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a3r12z3b/)**

As you will see in the demo, "start" will always restart the timer from zero. It doesn't behave like a stopwatch where the "start" button will restart from where the timer left off at the previous "stop", and a separate "reset" button is required (or a cyclic action on the "start" button). That would be more work.